# Can Anyone Share with me K-means code for intrusion detection in java?

Tags: data-mining, wireshark, k-means, intrusion-detection, jnetpcap

I have Searched everywhere and i got one code which works for integer values but i want code with string value ie to calculate centroids using string values can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## k-means *only* works on numerical values.

It's called "k-means" because it computes the *mean*. The mean makes only sense on continuous values. What would the mean of "apple" and "orange" be?!?

And how would you use it for intrusionndetection?

K-means is *way* too unreliable for intrusion detection, and you nedd something for data streams